# Elasticsearch: Failed to parse mapping [_doc]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a dynamic template mapping for the index and is continuously receiving the following error:

`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {dynamic_templates=[{articleNumber={mapping={type=text, fields={keyword={type=keyword}}}, match_mapping_type=*, match=articleNumber*}}]}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {dynamic_templates=[{articleNumber={mapping={type=text, fields={keyword={type=keyword}}}, match_mapping_type=*, match=articleNumber*}}]}]]];`

Here is the structure that I'm trying to create a mapping with:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "articleNumber": {
          "match_mapping_type": "*",
          "match": "articleNumber*",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It is a mistake in the mapping structure? or everything is ok here and I should take a look at the way of parsing the mapping object?

**UPDATED**

this is the code that I'm using to create a mapping:

```
CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest(indexName);
CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = getClient().indices().create(createIndexRequest.mapping(getIndexMapping()), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

private XContentBuilder getIndexMapping() throws IOException {
    String mappingObj = "{\"mappings\":{\"dynamic_templates\":[{\"articleNumber\":{\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"match\":\"articleNumber*\",\"mapping\":{\"type\":\"text\",\"fields\":{\"keyword\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"}}}}}]}}";
    XContentBuilder b = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().prettyPrint();
    try (XContentParser p = XContentFactory.xContent(XContentType.JSON).createParser(NamedXContentRegistry.EMPTY, 
            null, mappingObj)) {
        b.copyCurrentStructure(p);
    }
    System.err.println(b.toString());

    return b;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be correct. When do you get this error?

Comment: @OpsterESNinjaNishant, I've updated the post with a code sample

Comment: Your ES mapping seek correct and its working fine .i think u should look mapping object in your java code..

Comment: Object formed like this means(   "mappings": { "mappings": {.....}}   ) you will get this kind of error

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem? I also see mapping errors with ES7.

Comment: yes, @dhamo gave the answer, I was duplicating `mappings` object

Comment: @dhamo Please add your comment as an answer and Karen can accept that. I would be helpful for others searching for similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Following @dhamo's comment to the question, the fix was to switch from

> CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse =
> getClient().indices().create(createIndexRequest.***mapping***(getIndexMapping()),
> RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

to

> CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse =
> getClient().indices().create(createIndexRequest.***source***(getIndexMapping()),
> RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

The old .mappings() method on CreateIndexRequests now only declares the mapping portion of the index definition (with settings defined separately, with the .settings() method).  So now we just use .source() when we have a single json object for the index definition.